# How do I get vs2008's intellisense member list to show full signatures?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, settings, intellisense

I saw a blog post the other day that had a screen shot of intellisense's member list that looked like this:

```
DateTime. -> [Compare(DateTime, DateTime) int]
             [DaysInMonth(int, int)       int]
             ...
```

Instead of mine which looks like:

```
DateTime. -> [Compare    ]
             [DaysInMonth]
             ...
```

How do I setup my vs2008 IDE so that my member list looks like the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that they were using [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper)? ReSharper's Intellisense is definitely nicer than Visual Studio's - apart from anything else, when it's showing overloads, it shows several at a time - I can never stand the way Visual Studio does that...

I've just checked, and I don't believe ReSharper does this *by default* but there's an option under ReSharper / Options / Environment / Intellisense / Completion Appearance: "Show member signatures". Turning that on gives the parameter types as desired.

I don't *think* vanilla Visual Studio has an equivalent option.

Comment: You beat me to it. This is an option in ReSharper.

Comment: Awe man! I got excited that this was a vanilla option - just hard to find. I'm using code rush here :( - maybe they've got something similar. Thanks.

Comment: I really didn't like it that much .... it killed my IDE ... So i uninstalled it. But it worth trying it out ;)